# CSS Animatable table row width?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-tables

Take the following basic css table. Is it possible to set a table-cell to zero width and have it be animatable via css? The only way I can seem to hide a table-cell is to use `display: none`, but that isn't animatable. Is this possible?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
}
.center {
  width: 0%;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .left,
  .right,
  .center {
    width: 33.333%;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell left'>left</div>
    <div class='cell center'>center</div>
    <div class='cell right'>right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eswqwwod/).

Comment: Use inline-block instead of table-cell. Then you can do what you want.

Comment: Okay that helps thanks, but still what about the widths of the other cells? http://jsfiddle.net/eswqwwod/1/ They are off quite a bit. Where is the white space coming from?

Comment: You can empty out the content of the middle cell and add the word "center" back in with CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/eswqwwod/3/ Not sure if you only want that single word in the cell though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Animated table cell width changes

The magic sauce is to use [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values) on the table.

The width of the cell is changed to `0%` or `0px` — The length type used to shrink the cell *must* be the same as the length type used for the normal cell width. In the example below the normal width is `33%`, so the width changes to `0%`.

#### Transition example

If the animation is used to simply hide a table cell when the user interacts with it in some way, a `transition` property on the cells is all you need:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .4s;
}
.table:hover .center {
  width: 0%
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>left</div>
    <div class='cell center'>center</div>
    <div class='cell'>right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Animated example using keyframes

This method can also be used to manipulate the width of table cells in an animation:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .4s;
}
.center {
  animation: reduceWidth 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes reduceWidth {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 33%;
    background: #F00;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0%;
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>left</div>
    <div class='cell center'>center</div>
    <div class='cell'>right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add another container for content in the `.center` div like this:

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell left'>left</div>
        <div class='cell center'>
          <div class="hideme">center</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell right'>right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And set it to `display: none`

```
.hideme {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .left,
    .right,
    .center {
        width: 33.333%;
        color: red;
    }
    .hideme {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eswqwwod/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://jsbin.com/nozavu/edit?html,css,output)

```
-webkit-animation: mymove 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: mymove 1s;


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {width: 0px;}

    50%  {width: 50px}
    100% {width: 100px;}
}
```